# Please help me with resolving HDD mounting error code

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

```
Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/highpana/OS: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda5" "/media/highpana/OS"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
(udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the error message, the last part say:

> Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

Just choose one of those options, and your mount will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't shutdown Windows last time but you hibernate it (fast boot option):
just restart on Windows and shutdown it with `shutdown /s` in cmd.
(to open cmd right click on windows icon and click on open prompt as administrator)